# Bootstrap validation for dynamically generated checkboxes is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, jstl, bootstrapvalidator

**The following code creates checkboxes dynamically:**

```
<div class="user-all-services-info">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Select Services</label>
        <br>
        <c:if test="${!empty srvcLst}">
          <c:forEach items="${srvcLst}" var="srvc">
            <c:set var="id" scope="page" value="0"></c:set>
            <c:choose>
              <c:when test="${!empty smLst}">
                <c:forEach items="${smLst}" var="smLst">
                  <c:if test="${srvc.ssmsId == smLst[0]}">
                    <c:set var="id" value="1"></c:set>
                  </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
                <c:choose>
                  <c:when test="${id eq 1}">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label><input
                               type="checkbox"
                                 name="srvcId"
                                   value="${srvc.ssmsId}">
                        &nbsp;${srvc.srvcNm}
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  </c:when>
                </c:choose>
              </c:when>
            </c:choose>
          </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I wrote the following `Bootstrap` code to verify that at least one of the dynamically generated checkboxes has been selected (notice that this code is only applicable to the first checkbox; it does not work for the other checkboxes).

```
srvcId: {                                                       
    validators: {                                                       
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please select at least 1 service.'
        }
    }                                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is following changes to validate checkbox with same name

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="srvcId[]" value="${srvc.ssmsId}">&nbsp;${srvc.srvcNm}</label>
```

JS

```
'srvcId[]': {                                                       
    validators: {                                                       
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please select at least 1 service.'
        }
    }                                       
}
```

Here is [an example](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/examples/#fields-with-same-name) to validate checkbox of same name.